# Open squares are a generator of the Borel sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let K be the set of open squares in $\mathbb{R}^2$ i.e.

$K=\{(a,a+r) \times (b,b+r):a,b \in \mathbb{R}, r>0\} $

I have to show that $\sigma (K) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

I know that i have to show the two inclusions $\sigma (K) \subset  \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $ \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2) \subset \sigma (K)$.

I have already showed the first inclusion, but i can't figure out the second one.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show that $(a,a+r) \times (b,b+r) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Comment: Sorry it was the one i have showed. It is the other one, which costs me trouble.

Comment: I see. Which definition of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ do you use? The $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets...?

Comment: The first line of your question says "open rectangles" but the second line describes $K$ as the set of open squares (with sides parallel to the axes).  The result is true under either interpretation, but you should decide which one you want.

Comment: Oh sorry again. I meant squares. I have edited it.

Comment: Since the Borel algebra is generated by the open sets, to show it's included in $\sigma(K)$, the main work is to show that every open set is in $\sigma(K)$. In fact, you can show (perhaps more easily) the stronger statement that every open set is a union of open squares with rational corners.

Comment: But how can i do that? I am a little lost.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, it suffices to show that any open set is in $\sigma(K)$.

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be an open set.

1. Show that for any $x \in U$ there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Q}^2$ such that $$K_{x} := (a,a+1/k) \times (b,b+1/k) \subseteq U.$$
2. Use that there are at least countably many sets of the form $$(a,a+1/k) \times (b,b+1/k), \qquad a,b \in \mathbb{Q},k \in \mathbb{N},$$ in order to conclude that $U \in \sigma(K)$.

Comment: Thank you. Is this argumentation correct: Because U is open there exists for every x in U a ball with center x and radius r>0. We can inscribe a square into this ball rational endpoints and side lenght 1/k (k natural) where x is contained. Because of that: Kx:=(a,a+1/k)×(b,b+1/k)⊆U. Since every square is uniquely determined by its side length, there are at most #Q x Q=#N many squares in the union.

Comment: @mamo Squares are not uniquely determined by its side length (we can move it around!), but by its vertices... Except for that, your argumentation is correct.

Comment: Thank you. And then i can conclude that U∈σ(K) where a,b is rational, which is again is a subset of σ(K), where a, b is real values. I that right?

Comment: @mamo Yes, exactly.

Comment: Great. Thank you again.